# Xcode 6 can't pass paths with spaces to Clang

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode6

I have a project that links with [libpq](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq.html). The path to my project includes a folder with spaces in its name and this seems to throw Xcode. I developed this particular project in Xcode 4 and compiled it in Xcode 5 so I think it's a new issue.

When building the project, I get this error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/lapinrigolo/Projects/Lost'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LBytes/Tuples/SQLConnector/SQLConnector/libpq/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LBytes/Tuples/SQLConnector/SQLConnector/libpqtypes/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LBytes/Tuples/SQLConnector/SQLConnector'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LBytes/Tuples/SQLConnector'
```

The path I have is:

`~/Projects/Lost Bytes/Tuples/SQLConnector/...` where the ellipsis represents the files and directories I want to compile. Has anyone seen this? Is it possible to fix this without renaming that directory?

Comment: use "quotes" in Xcode settings

Comment: I dragged and dropped the files into Xcode, I didn't add the path manually. Is there a file I can edit?

Comment: you can just delete them and drag & drop again...

Comment: The original project still fails because of the path.

Comment: Well, it worked. I removed and re-added a couple of directories and Clang was happy. Can you turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks you have missing quotes in your build settings and the space make Xcode think it is two paths instead of one.

the easy fix is delete them and add them again (drag & drop).